# Extracting Dataframes from a Dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I am working on a project which uses a python script to read in multiply .xls files with the goal to have one data frame containing all data points across all files. Sounds simple right.

Since the header names and position of the header differ from file to file (and some with additional columns too), my script saves each file as a data frame within a dictionary. This is good as it can capture all the data points from each file. Each data frame can be called using the keys function.

My project will consist of ~1500 .xls files to be read in, but for now I am only using 5 files to get the code working.

However, the problem is how to extract each data frame saved to the dictionary and convert it into one single view.

The header names, can previously be mentioned, can vary from each data frame within the dictionary as follows:

Sample file 1:
`Security Type |  Primary Source | Secondary Source | Pricing Logic | Valuation Point`

Sample file 2:
`Security Type |  Primary Source | Secondary Source | Pricing Logic | Valuation Point`

Sample file 3:
`Security Type |  Secondary Source | Primary Source | Pricing Logic`

How do I iterate through this dictionary to produce a single view/data frame knowing the header can be in a different position and some may have more header names than others but all headers are of equal importance and cannot be omitted.

Comment: So to summarize the script should read all excel files, and combine them in one Dataframe, matching possible headers if they exist twice or more?

Comment: [`pd.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) should take care of this for you.  Look at the examples provided.  The order of columns is irrelevant as long as the column names are the same.

Answer (score -1):

Try the following. Below you have two dummy `dataframes`, both include columns `A` and `B`, and a third exclusive column (`X` and `Y` respectively), and the column order is inconsistent.

Assume that the columns you want in the final view are defined in `cols` (`A` and `B` in this case).

Following the steps below - iterating through the dictionary and saving the result in a final `dff`, using `pd.concat` - you can achieve what you're asking for.

```
dfs = {
    'df1': pd.DataFrame({'A': ['1A'], 'B': ['1B'], 'X': ['X']}),
    'df2': pd.DataFrame({'Y': ['Y'], 'A': ['2A'], 'B': ['2B']})    
}

cols = ['A', 'B']

dff = pd.DataFrame()
for k in dfs.keys():
    dff = pd.concat([dff, dfs[k][cols]]).reset_index(drop=True)
    
print(dff)
    A   B
0  1A  1B
1  2A  2B
```